# SharpSVN: Unable to connect to a repository at URL | Access Forbidden

Tags: c#, svn, authentication, sharpsvn

```
            client.Authentication.DefaultCredentials = new NetworkCredential("login",
                                                                "pswd",
                                                                 new Uri("address").AbsoluteUri);
            client.Authentication.SslServerTrustHandlers += delegate(object sender, SvnSslServerTrustEventArgs e)
            {
                e.AcceptedFailures = e.Failures;
                e.Save = true; // Save acceptance to authentication store
            };
```

I try to connect to read-only repo, and it gives me an exception:

```
'Unable to connect to a repository at URL'|'Access Forbidden'
```

URL and login\password are correct, of course.

Tried to connect from VisualSVN and TotroiseSVN and it is all right, no problems.

But SharpSVN gives me a headache with that stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
client.Authentication.ForceCredentials("login", "pswd");
```